# Does this translation for "wondrous things are found in new beginnings and opportunities" fit?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, sentence-translation

I currently have "mira in novis initiis et occasionibus reperiuntur" as a potential translation but I'm unsure if it fits the meaning.